# Internet connection randomly drops

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking, wifi-configuration

So, my PC is connected to a router via WiFi, which is connected to DSL.

At random, my internet connection will drop, but I am still connected to the router via WiFi. This does not seem to happen to any other device.

I thought it could be because of DHCP IP address lease expiring, but I have a static internal IPv4. What else could be causing this?

Comment: Connect a different device to your router and see if that connection drops as well. So divide the problem in half and determine if Router or Computer.

Comment: My understanding is that your device showed as Wi-Fi connected but you cannot access to the Internet. Am I right? If the other device doesn't have this problem, I would suggest you could collect network traffic via Wireshark or Network Monitor for further troubleshooting.